# How to Build a Covariance Matrix for assets imported from a excel sheet in Python?

Tags: python

I have read an excel file (it has around 6k rows and 200 columns, being the first row the asset names and below are the dates with asset prices)

I want the covariance matrix of all assets for the last two years (about 700 rows) implemented in Python

(I will run a Portfolio optimization later)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! See also: [ask]

Answer (score 0):

You can use pandas to get covariance

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('FileName.xlsx', sheetname='Sheet1')
mat_corr = df.cov()
```

this will give covariance matrix for all the excel. You should first filter the relevant assets, this depends on the format of the date in your spreadsheet